# Prevent WPF from catching F5 so that i can use it for my own purposes?

Tags: wpf, refresh, hotkeys, f5

I want a refresh hotkey for my application, the standard key for "refresh" is F5 for most programs. So i would like to use that hotkey for my program aswell. The problem is that WPF uses F5 to refresh Frames.

I managed to turn off refresh on Frames with this in the codebehind for the usercontrol with the frame:

```
    private void pageFrame_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Refresh)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

However, this still "catches" the keypress so that i cannot detect it else where in the program. It nullifies the key press as though it never happened. How can i stop Frame from refreshing when i press F5 and at the same time use F5 in other places?

I detect keypresses with:

```
    public static void KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.F6: //Send Group
                //THIS HERE WORKS!
                break;
            case Key.F5: //Refresh Group
                //THIS HERE DOES NOT WORK!
            break;
        }
    }
```

This function is subscribed to the main window's "KeyDown" event.

Comment: Handle the Window.PreviewKeyDown event. If the F5 key is pressed, then set `e.Handled=true;`

Comment: My first thought is.... do not use frame and page. Usercontrols can be data templated out from viewmodels and are lighter weight. Don't come with all the baggage frames have,

Comment: *"so that i cannot detect it else where in the program."* - If that is your original goal, then simply handle the tunneling event version: `PreviewKeyDown`.

Comment: Why set e.Handled=true? My problem is that the handler is already true after WPF built in shortkeys for frames so it wont be handled in KeyDown event. 

I guess not using frames is probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this page with the same problem. I fixed it by using *ContentControl* instead of *Frame* and *UserControl* instead of *Page*.

I just used Frame and Page because of their names so i figured that was what you are supposed to do. But using ContentControl and UserControl instead gives you more freedom and there is nothing Frame/Page can do that ContentControl/UserControl cant be programmed to do.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx